# Write with cursor into a table (table name as parameter)

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, fetch

How could I insert in a table using CURSOR with a name gives as a parameter? 
Thanks

```
PROCEDURE delta (pTableName IN VARCHAR2, pStichTag  IN DATE) IS 
   lTabName :=  VARCHAR(30);
   v_stmt_str := VARCHAR(4000); 
   cCursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
   BEGIN
       lTabName :=  substr(pTableName,5);
       v_stmt_str := 'SELECT * FROM '|| lTableName ||' WHERE dwh_date =     
       to_date('||pStichTag||','DD.MM.YY');

   OPEN cCursor  FOR v_stmt_str USING 'MANAGER';
   LOOP
       FETCH cCursor INTO pTableNAME%ROWTYPE;
       -- UPATE pTableName SET some WHERE this line
   END LOOP;
CLOSE cCursor;
```

Comment: Do you want to select some data or update a table?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to perform the update:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE ' || pTableName ||
                  ' SET SOME_COLUMN = 12345 WHERE SOME_OTHER_COLUMN = ''xyz''';
```

However, you're going to have to re-do your cursor logic. Because you don't know the table name you don't know which fields will be fetched prior to opening the cursor, so you're going to have to hard-code the field names to be fetched instead of using `*`. If that's not to your liking you'll have to use the DBMS_SQL package, which allows for more flexibility - but I'll warn you, it's rather complex to use.

Comment: Hi, I used LISTAGG, it seems to work. But my problem is in the FETCH line, when I try to fetch the cursor, I receive an error, also with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. Is it possible to fetch a cursor with the name of a table as parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code snippet

```
PROCEDURE delta (pTableName IN VARCHAR2, pStichTag  IN DATE) 
IS 
   lTabName  VARCHAR(30); -- removed :=
   v_stmt_str VARCHAR(4000); -- removed :=
   cCursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
   BEGIN
       lTabName :=  substr(pTableName,5); -- I dont understand why only first five digits of table name is used. May be your logic
       v_stmt_str := 'SELECT * FROM '|| lTableName ||' WHERE dwh_date =     
       to_date('''||pStichTag||''',''DD.MM.YY'')'; -- added few ' for proper string concatenation

   OPEN cCursor  FOR v_stmt_str USING MANAGER; -- removed ' from MANAGER, MANAGER must be some variable and for your cusrsor, there is no bind variable so there is no need of USING clause at all
-- You can use just: OPEN cCursor  FOR v_stmt_str;
   LOOP
       FETCH cCursor INTO pTableNAME%ROWTYPE;
       -- UPATE pTableName SET some WHERE this line
   END LOOP;
CLOSE cCursor;
```

I hope this will be useful.

Cheers!!

Comment: FETCH cCursor INTO pTableNAME%ROWTYPE;

I receive an error in this line: PLS-00308 this construct is not allowed as the origin of an assignment

I tried also with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, but it doesn't work.

I have Oracle SQL Server 12c Release 1.

Comment: Yes, It cannot be dynamic. You can use `For loop` instead of `FETCH`

Comment: Please, Could you write an example in my case? I tried all the possibility but I am not able to do that.